# Grep lines that contain "1111-11-11" or "2382-21-20". (Any Numbers)

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have tried to do this and I came up with this

```
grep -E '\<[0-9]{4}"-"[0-9]{2}"-"[0-9]{2}\>'
```

It doesn't work and the reason for that is the `"-"` and multiple grep things, so I tried dividing them with a pipe like this

```
grep -E '\<[0-9]{4}-|[0-9]{2}-|[0-9]{2}\>'
```

But it still matches lines like `4444`, or similar. Anyone know how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Your Questions doesn't contain the less-than and greater-than signs, but the search and the answers - what role do they play?

Comment: `\<` is a grep-E regex meta that stands for in the beginning of a word (word boundary). `\>` end of a word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are overquoting...

```
grep -E '\<[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\>'
```

Answer (score 0):

[JJoao](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176428/80886) is right about quotes, additionally can make it a little bit shorter:

```
grep -E '\<[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}\>'
```